# Laravel cache expire sooner than its ttl when using file driver

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-8

When I use file file driver for cache, the cache file gets created and accessible, but for about only 1 minutes. it seems ttl parameter has no affect.

```php
Route::get('setCache', function () {
    Cache::store('file')->put('testCache1', 'testCache1 value', now()->addHours(12));
});
Route::get('getCache', function () {
    dd(Cache::store('file')->get('testCache1'));
});
```

After visiting `/setCache` cache file get created, and I can see the cached value in `/getCache` path. but after about a minute or less, the `/getCache` shows null and the cached file gets deleted.
the above code works correct when I use `database` driver.
since the cache get created and accessible for a short time, I don't think it's related to permissions.

Comment: Are there any scheduled tasks or job in your project that is clearing the cache?

Comment: there are serveral tasks, but none of them clear cache directly, I'll disable them to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The informations are not enough, you must have clearing the cache somewhere else in your application.
but make sure you dont use `Cache::flush` anywhere in your all Laravel application**s** in your machine, it doesn't respect the 'prefix', see [the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#removing-items-from-the-cache).

Comment: the problem was `Cache::flush` called in one of the livewire components, I really didn't think about it. thanks.

Comment: I am so delighted that my answer helped you.